# Are canonical parameters and natural parameters always the same in exponential family distributions?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-family

So far I have seen three formulations of the exponential family:
$$
1.\;\large f_Y(\mathbf{y}\,;\,\vec{\theta})=h(\mathbf{y}) \exp \left(\mathbf{b}(\vec{\theta}) \cdot \mathbf{T}(\mathbf{y})-A(\vec{\theta})\right)
$$

$$
2.\;\large f_Y(\mathbf{y}\,;\,\vec{\theta})=h(\mathbf{y}) \exp \left(\boldsymbol{\eta}(\vec{\theta}) \cdot \mathbf{T}(\mathbf{y})-A(\boldsymbol{\eta}(\vec{\theta}))\right)
$$

$$
3.\;\large f_Y(\mathbf{y}\,;\,\boldsymbol{\eta})=h(\mathbf{y}) \exp \left(\boldsymbol{\eta} \cdot \mathbf{T}(\mathbf{y})-A(\boldsymbol{\eta})\right)
$$

- In formulation 1, $\vec{\theta}$ is called the canonical parameter whereas $\mathbf{b}(\mathbf{\vec \theta})$ is referred to as the natural parameter.
- In 2, $\mathbf{\vec \theta}$ is called both the canonical and natural parameter.
- In 3, $\boldsymbol{\eta}$ is called both the canonical and natural parameter.

To my understanding, an exponential family pdf is said to be in its canonical form when $\large \boldsymbol{\eta}(\mathbf{\vec \theta}) = \mathbf{\vec \theta}$ .
So, in the canonical form, both the terms canonical parameter and natural parameter can be used interchangeably.

But what if the exponential family pdf is **not** in the canonical. Can they still be used interchangeably?
I really need someone to clarify this terminology for me.